# How to pause the autoplay of carousel_pro when the image is pressed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Actually, the carousel_slider have the pauseAutoPlayOnTouch that works perfectly but I'm working with a Stateless Widget component into the Stateful Widget. So, I'm trying to pause using the carousel_pro and I have no idea how to solve this.

There's a property called **onImageTap** and this can be the answer.

This is a part of the code where I set up the Carousel configs.

```
                dotSpacing: 15.0,
                dotColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
                dotIncreasedColor: Color.fromRGBO(203, 0, 0, 1),
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayDuration: Duration(seconds: 10),
                indicatorBgPadding: 0.0,
                dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: true,
```

Answer (score -1):

```
            dotSpacing: 15.0,
            dotColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
            dotIncreasedColor: Color.fromRGBO(203, 0, 0, 1),
            autoplay: false,
            indicatorBgPadding: 0.0,
            dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
            borderRadius: true,
```

EDIT -

Providing the explanation-

You have to set the autoplay property when the imageTap event occurs. For this do the following steps

1. Add a class property `bool isAutoPlayEnabled = true`
2. In the CarouselOptions, set `autoplay: isAutoPlayEnabled`
3. onImageTap do `setState(){ isAutoPlayEnabled = ! isAutoPlayEnabled; }`

Now the widget tree will be recreated and the carousel page will be paused.

Another theory- i dont know if it will work or not - try wrapping the carousel with `GestureDetector` and use its `onTap:` to set the value of `isAutoPlayEnabled`

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: While this might answer the question, providing details as to how to reached the conclusion and your thought process will surely help the fellow asker. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)